# How can i change this reducer code to find the longest words (and the length) rather than it finding the frequency of the words?

Tags: python, mapreduce

REDUCER CODE    This code finds the frequency of the words from a text file, and I would like to know how to change this to find the longest words in the text file and print them out eg. "The longest word has 13 characters. The result includes: "

```
import sys
results = {}
for line in sys.stdin:
    word, frequency = line.strip().split('\t', 1)
    results[word]=results.get(word,0) + int(frequency)
    words = list(results.keys())
    words.sort()
    for word in words:
        print(word,results[word])
```

MAPPER CODE

```
import sys
for line in sys.stdin:
    for word in line.strip().split():
        print (word , "1")
```

Comment: just loop through all the words, and keep the longest one in a variable?

Comment: There's no reason for the mapper to output every single word it sees. Why not have the mapper only output one record - the longest word that it sees - and then have a single reducer pick the longest word from those. You want all map output records to go to the same reducer so you'll need to think about your key design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to keep all words then you could do something like this:

```
longest = set()
max_length = 0
for line in sys.stdin:
    for word in line.strip().split():
        length = len(word)
        if length > max_length:
            max_length = length
            longest = {word}
        elif length == max_length:
            longest.add(word)

print(longest)
```

If you want to keep them, grouped by length, you could use a [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
from collections import defaultdict

words_length = defaultdict(set)
for line in sys.stdin:
    for word in line.strip().split():
        words_length[len(word)].add(word)

print(words_length[max(words_length)])
```

Comment: It's not a good idea to store every record in memory in a MapReduce job. Only keep track of the current longest word.

Comment: @BenWatson Agreed, if that is what the op is actually looking for. But I'm not sure it is, the first part of the question sounds different.

Comment: @timus - you are right.  I am trying to complete an exercise that was set and we were given the mapper and reducer as displayed and had to right a regular python code to get the answer - which I did and there are two words in the file that are both 13 characters in length - so they both need to be output.  

I then have to modify the mapper and reducer to get this same output. so from mu understanding the mapper is giving the reducer all of the words and then the reducer will pick the the longest words in the file and output them. 
I think your answer will get me what I need - thank you

Answer (score 0):

To build on my suggestion (loop through words, keep longest in variable):

```
longest = ""

for line in something:
    for word in line.lower().split():
        if len(word.strip()) > len(longest):
            longest = word.strip()

print("Longest word is:", longest, "with the length of:", len(longest))
```

Comment: Keep in mind that when running this through Hadoop-Streaming Mapreduce functions, multiple file-parts are read at a time, each having their own longest words... Therefore, you need a reducer function to find the longest of those

Comment: Feel free to edit the answer, but OP didn't provide much info in this regard, so I can't really help in this case